# Second monitor only turns on when a window is open in its viewport

Tags: windows-10

I have a second monitor connected to my windows 10 machine, and the second monitor displays a black screen until an open window is moved onto it. This isn't generally a problem, except when I minimize an app on the second monitor, at which point I can't reopen it because the monitor goes dark!

I believe there is simply a setting I need to change somewhere to fix this recent behavior, but I can't find it. I'm not quite sure how to go about searching for an answer to this problem either! How do I turn off this auto shutoff?